# UIAlertview button action to change to another viewcontroller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview

I am just getting into Xcode programming, and I need code so that when I click a button, it is a confirmation to take me into another ViewController.

I have an X button on the page, and when clicked I need a UIAlertview to pop up saying 'cancel' and 'next', and when next is pressed, i want it to change to another ViewController. These cancel and next buttons need to be side by side.

Comment: Read how to go to another `UIViewController`, read how to know which button of an `UIAlertView` (tip: look for `UIAlertViewDelegate`) is clicked. Try it, try to understand, and if you have a issue or questions, ask them. But you have to, at least try.

Comment: I have tried to link viewcontroller to button, but all i have managed to do is get URL working when alert button is clicked, i cant link it to different viewcontroller!

Comment: If you tried something, at least give us some code.

Answer (score 0):

First thing you need to do is make sure the view with a button is a delegate of UIAlertView.

```
@interface ViewController() <UIAlertViewDelegate>
```

Then you need to add a touch up inside action to the button in your view. When the button is pressed, it creates the alertView and shows it. Note, its delegate is self.

```
- (IBAction)clickButton:(id)sender {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Test" message: @"Message" delegate: self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Next", nil];
    [alert show];
}
```

Lastly, you create the delegate function. This is triggered whenever a button is clicked in the alertView. buttonIndex corresponds to the button that was clicked, so we want to present the view when the 1st button is pressed (0 corresponds to cancel, 1 corresponds to next). Realistically, you'd probably want to present a custom view controller that you define.

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    if(buttonIndex == 1){
        UIViewController* newView = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
        [self presentViewController:newView animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
```